# Altering python-gearman worker tasks during job processing

Tags: python, gearman, python-gearman

I'm attempting to change the tasks available on a python-gearman worker during its work cycle.  My reason for doing this is to allow me a little bit of control over my worker processes and allowing them to reload from a database.  I need every worker to reload at regular intervals, but I don't want to simply kill the processes, and I want the service to be constantly available which means that I have to reload in batches.  So I would have 4 workers reloading while another 4 workers are available to process, and then reload the next 4 workers.

Process:

1. Start reload process 4 times.

   1. unregister the `reload` process
   2. reload the dataset
   3. register a `finishReload` task
   4. return
2. Repeat step 1 until there are no workers with the `reload` task registered.
3. Start `finishReload`(1) task until there are no workers with the `finishReload` task available.

(1) the finishReload task unregisters the `finishReload` task and registers the `reload` task and then returns.

Now, the problem that I'm running into is that the job fails when I change the tasks that are available to the worker process.  There are no error messages or exceptions, just an "ERROR" in the gearmand log.  Here's a quick program that replicates the problem.

### WORKER

```
import gearman 
def reversify(gmWorker, gmJob): 
        return "".join(gmJob.data[::-1]) 
def strcount(gmWorker, gmJob): 
        gmWorker.unregister_task('reversify')  # problem line 
        return str(len(gmJob.data)) 
worker = gearman.GearmanWorker(['localhost:4730']) 
worker.register_task('reversify', reversify) 
worker.register_task('strcount', strcount) 
while True: 
        worker.work()
```

### CLIENT

```
import gearman 
client = gearman.GearmanClient(['localhost:4730']) 
a = client.submit_job('reversify', 'spam and eggs') 
print a.result 
>>> sgge dna maps 

a = client.submit_job('strcount', 'spam and eggs') 
...
```

Please let me know if there are anything things that I can elucidate.

EDIT: I know that someone will ask to see the log I mentioned.  I've posted this question to the gearman group on Google as well, and [log is available there](http://groups.google.com/group/gearman/browse_thread/thread/9987337cae4adf52).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like subclassing the GearmanWorker class and adding a few flags can work around this issue.  I need to allow the job to complete before I start issuing new commands from the worker to the server, which seems to interrupt the current job.  So if we overwrite the `on_job_complete` function we can check for the enable/disable flag and act on those after we issue the `send_job_complete` command.  The new worker program follows:

WORKER

```
import gearman

def reversify(gmWorker, gmJob):
        return "".join(gmJob.data[::-1])

def enable_reversify(gmWorker, gmJob):
        myWorker.enableReversify = 1
        return 'OK'

def strcount(gmWorker, gmJob):
        myWorker.enableReversify = -1
        return str(len(gmJob.data))

class myWorker(gearman.GearmanWorker):

        enableReversify = 0 # 0 = do nothing, -1 = turn off, 1 = turn on

        def on_job_complete(self, current_job, job_result):
                self.send_job_complete(current_job, job_result)
                ### check the flag here and enable or disable tasks ###
                if myWorker.enableReversify == -1:
                        self.unregister_task('reversify')
                if myWorker.enableReversify == 1:
                        self.register_task('reversify', reversify)
                myWorker.enableReversify = 0 # reset the flag
                return True

worker = myWorker(['localhost:4730']) 
worker.register_task('reversify', reversify)
worker.register_task('strcount', strcount)
worker.register_task('enableReversify', enable_reversify)

while True:
        worker.work()
```

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, the problem would seem to be that you are starting a job, then de-registering the workers ability to do that job from the job server before its finished.

Comment: figured out a solution.  Not particularly elegant, but it does the trick.  My first inclination was the same as yours, although I had ruled that out a long time ago.  The same symptoms would occur when registering new tasks.  I appears that interrupting conversation with the client to talk to the server was a no no.